# html tags output as part of variable

Tags: php, html

the code below is supposed to create hospital name hyperlinked to it's location but when I output $hyperlink variable to send, it just outputs hospital location alongside hospital name. I'm working on notepad++ and running my code in google chrome. Could it be that php is not processing html correctly. Btw, it also concatenates html tags (inside $hyperlink) as part of the output. Please help

```
    while($processtable=mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetchospitalperson)){
       // $messagebody= "Patient Name: ".$processtable['firstname']." ".$processtable['fathername']." ".$processtable['lastname']."  "."Hospital Name:"; 
        $messagebody = "Patient Name: ".$processtable['firstname']." ".$processtable['fathername']." ".$processtable['lastname']."  "."Hospital Name:".PHP_EOL; 
        //$hyperlink= new DOMDocument();
        //$hyperlink->loadHTML("<html><body><a href='<".$processtable['geolocation']."'>" .$processtable['hospitalname']."</a></body></html>"); 
        $hyperlink = "<html><body><a href='<".$processtable['geolocation']."'>".$processtable['hospitalname']."</a></body></html>".PHP_EOL;
         //Name of the person that needs the blood transfusion along with hospital he is staying at,hyperlinked to its location
         $string .= $messagebody."  ".$hyperlink.PHP_EOL ;
        }
    $message= "Dear"." ".$firstname." ".$lastname.",".PHP_EOL .$string; 
    if(isset($sendtoperson)){   
        if(mail($to,$header,$message)){
            echo "Sent";
        }
        else{ echo "Not sent";}
    }
```

Comment: `'<"` does not look right in `<a href='<"` remove the `<`

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._ -  next time post the HTML output

Comment: I am using < as a short hand for <?php?> tags that are supposed to run location code. btw I tried <?php?> tags gave me a headache

Comment: If I remove < from <a href how I going to run php code to fetch location from database

Comment: No need there. You are concatenating correctly when you have `"<html><body><a href='".$processtable['geolocation']."'>".$processtable['hospitalname']."</a>"`

Comment: There is no difference to `"Patient Name: ".$processtable['firstname']." "` except the href has single quotes around the location

Comment: You do need to use headers for the HTML though and no need to have a html and body tag for each line: https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/